# Edit xml file with PHP or XSLT

Tags: php, xml, xslt, feed

i need big help from you, i am totaly lost in this problem, i googling all the time but nothing what can help me. When I found some solutions, it did not work.....Help me pleas :/

Edit it in PHP or XSLT pleas, Thx.

**Input:**

```
<SHOP>
    <SHOPITEM>
        <PRODUCTNAME>Table</PRODUCTNAME>
        <DESCRIPTION>slaklasdk askdalsd dsasd</DESCRIPTION>
        <URL>http://www.google.com/</URL>
        <IMGURL>http://www.google.com/</IMGURL>
        <PRICE>79</PRICE>
        <CATEGORIES>
            <CATEGORY>Work, table</CATEGORY>
        </CATEGORIES>
        <MOTIVES>
            <MOTIVE>Brown oak</MOTIVE>
        </MOTIVES>
        <SIZES>
            <SIZE>
                <SIZEID>38626</SIZEID>
                <SIZENAME>uni</SIZENAME>
                <STOREPIECES>12</STOREPIECES>
            </SIZE>
        </SIZES>
</SHOPITEM>
<SHOPITEM>
        <PRODUCTNAME>Book</PRODUCTNAME>
        <DESCRIPTION>asdasdasdawra asdaseasd</DESCRIPTION>
        <URL>http://www.google.com/</URL>
        <IMGURL>http://www.google.com/</IMGURL>
        <PRICE>79</PRICE>
        <CATEGORIES>
            <CATEGORY>Book, Magazine</CATEGORY>
        </CATEGORIES>
        <MOTIVES>
            <MOTIVE>Black with blue stars</MOTIVE>
        </MOTIVES>
        <SIZES>
            <SIZE>
                <SIZEID>38626</SIZEID>
                <SIZENAME>uni</SIZENAME>
                <STOREPIECES>0</STOREPIECES>
            </SIZE>
        </SIZES>
    </SHOPITEM>
```

**I NEED:**

1)delete `<URL> and <IMGURL>`

2)`<PRODUCTNAME>` rename `<title>`

3)`<CATEGORIES>` delete and rename `<CATEGORY> on <ctg_0>`

4)`<MOTIVE>` merge with `<DESCRIPTION>` and delete `<MOTIVES>,<MOTIVE>`

5)delete `<SIZES>, <SIZE> and <SIZEID>` after that `<SIZENAME>` merge with `<DISCRIPTION>` and add new element `<unit>0</unit>` and rename `<STOREPIECES>` on `<pieces>`

**Output:**

```
<SHOP>
    <SHOPITEM>
        <title>Table</title>
        <DESCRIPTION>slaklasdk askdalsd dsasd, Motive:Brown oak, size:uni</DESCRIPTION>
        <PRICE>79</PRICE>
        <ctg_0>Book, Magazine</ctg_0>
        <pieces>12</pieces>
        <unit>0</unit>
    </SHOPITEM>
    <SHOPITEM>
        <title>Book</title>
        <DESCRIPTION>asdasdasdawra asdaseasd, Motive:Black with blue stars, size:uni</DESCRIPTION>
        <PRICE>79</PRICE>
        <ctg_0>Book, Magazine</ctg_0>
        <pieces>0</pieces>
        <unit>0</unit>
    </SHOPITEM>
</SHOP>
```

Comment: **I NEED** is not a question, and this is not a coding service. If you're stuck on a **specific** issue, ask about *that*.

Comment: Sorry, but my english is not good so i use straigh word and you dont have to be so aggressive.

Comment: Your English has nothing to do with it. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask And don't confuse terse with aggressive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn XSL. Quick crash course:
xsl matches the least generic match first so if you have a rule for * and a rule for URL, it will apply the rule for URL instead of *.
. is the current node.
* are all child nodes of the current node.
text() is all the text under the current node, or a single text node in a match.
@* are all the attributes of the current node.
name(.) is the name of the current node.

Therefore, this recursively copies (piecemeal) every node/text/attribute in the file:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{name(.)}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|text()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|text()">
    <xsl:copy-of select='.'/>
</xsl:template>
```

Now add the more specific matches for those you want to change. If you want to remove a node:

```
<xsl:template match="URL|IMGURL"/><!-- Do nothing, don't copy it -->
```

Remember, the more specific match comes first. Renaming a node, replace {name(.)} (the name of the current node) with what you want to change it to.

That should get you started, the rest is up to you.

Comment: "*this recursively copies (piecemeal) every node/text/attribute in the file*" Actually, it only copies element, attribute and text nodes, not *every* node. Other nodes, such as namespaces, comments and processing instructions will not be copied. (To be more precise, it doesn't even copy the elements - it creates new ones with the same name - there **is** a difference.) See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT

Comment: I wasn't being precise, I was being helpful.